# How do I get the dots to go away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a pre made website.  I am working on it, and I am okay with CSS and HTML, but I don't have much experience with Java.  I think that the problem is with Java.  I would really like the dots to not be there where the list items just rotate without the dots appearing below.

[image]

```js
/*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */
(function(c,I,B){c.fn.responsiveSlides=function(l){var a=c.extend({auto:!0,speed:500,timeout:4E3,pager:!1,nav:!1,random:!1,pause:!1,pauseControls:!0,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",maxwidth:"",navContainer:"",manualControls:"",namespace:"rslides",before:c.noop,after:c.noop},l);return this.each(function(){B++;var f=c(this),s,r,t,m,p,q,n=0,e=f.children(),C=e.size(),h=parseFloat(a.speed),D=parseFloat(a.timeout),u=parseFloat(a.maxwidth),g=a.namespace,d=g+B,E=g+"_nav "+d+"_nav",v=g+"_here",j=d+"_on",
w=d+"_s",k=c("<ul class='"+g+"_tabs "+d+"_tabs' />"),x={"float":"left",position:"relative",opacity:1,zIndex:2},y={"float":"none",position:"absolute",opacity:0,zIndex:1},F=function(){var b=(document.body||document.documentElement).style,a="transition";if("string"===typeof b[a])return!0;s=["Moz","Webkit","Khtml","O","ms"];var a=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1),c;for(c=0;c<s.length;c++)if("string"===typeof b[s[c]+a])return!0;return!1}(),z=function(b){a.before(b);F?(e.removeClass(j).css(y).eq(b).addClass(j).css(x),
n=b,setTimeout(function(){a.after(b)},h)):e.stop().fadeOut(h,function(){c(this).removeClass(j).css(y).css("opacity",1)}).eq(b).fadeIn(h,function(){c(this).addClass(j).css(x);a.after(b);n=b})};a.random&&(e.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5}),f.empty().append(e));e.each(function(a){this.id=w+a});f.addClass(g+" "+d);l&&l.maxwidth&&f.css("max-width",u);e.hide().css(y).eq(0).addClass(j).css(x).show();F&&e.show().css({"-webkit-transition":"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out","-moz-transition":"opacity "+
h+"ms ease-in-out","-o-transition":"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out",transition:"opacity "+h+"ms ease-in-out"});if(1<e.size()){if(D<h+100)return;if(a.pager&&!a.manualControls){var A=[];e.each(function(a){a+=1;A+="<li><a href='#' class='"+w+a+"'>"+a+"</a></li>"});k.append(A);l.navContainer?c(a.navContainer).append(k):f.after(k)}a.manualControls&&(k=c(a.manualControls),k.addClass(g+"_tabs "+d+"_tabs"));(a.pager||a.manualControls)&&k.find("li").each(function(a){c(this).addClass(w+(a+1))});if(a.pager||a.manualControls)q=
k.find("a"),r=function(a){q.closest("li").removeClass(v).eq(a).addClass(v)};a.auto&&(t=function(){p=setInterval(function(){e.stop(!0,!0);var b=n+1<C?n+1:0;(a.pager||a.manualControls)&&r(b);z(b)},D)},t());m=function(){a.auto&&(clearInterval(p),t())};a.pause&&f.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()});if(a.pager||a.manualControls)q.bind("click",function(b){b.preventDefault();a.pauseControls||m();b=q.index(this);n===b||c("."+j).queue("fx").length||(r(b),z(b))}).eq(0).closest("li").addClass(v),
a.pauseControls&&q.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()});if(a.nav){g="<a href='#' class='"+E+" prev'>"+a.prevText+"</a><a href='#' class='"+E+" next'>"+a.nextText+"</a>";l.navContainer?c(a.navContainer).append(g):f.after(g);var d=c("."+d+"_nav"),G=d.filter(".prev");d.bind("click",function(b){b.preventDefault();b=c("."+j);if(!b.queue("fx").length){var d=e.index(b);b=d-1;d=d+1<C?n+1:0;z(c(this)[0]===G[0]?b:d);if(a.pager||a.manualControls)r(c(this)[0]===G[0]?b:d);a.pauseControls||m()}});
a.pauseControls&&d.hover(function(){clearInterval(p)},function(){m()})}}if("undefined"===typeof document.body.style.maxWidth&&l.maxwidth){var H=function(){f.css("width","100%");f.width()>u&&f.css("width",u)};H();c(I).bind("resize",function(){H()})}})}})(jQuery,this,0);
```

```css
#slider3,#slider4  {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rslides_tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  max-width: 540px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.rslides_tabs li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.rslides_tabs a {
  width: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline;
}
.rslides_tabs li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.events {
  list-style: none;
}
.callbacks_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.callbacks {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.callbacks li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.callbacks img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.callbacks .caption {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-shadow: none;
 color: #fff;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin: 0;
 max-width: none;
 top: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}
.callbacks_nav {
   position: absolute;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 top: 61%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: 3;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 62px;
 width: 45px;
 margin-top: -65px;
}


.callbacks_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
a.callbacks_nav.callbacks1_nav.prev {
 background: transparent url("../images/themes.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  left: -3.1%;
}
.callbacks_nav.next {
 background: transparent url("../images/themes.png") no-repeat -46px 0px;
  left: 100%;
}
#slider3-pager a,#slider4-pager a  {
  display: inline-block;
}
#slider3-pager span,#slider4-pager span{
}
#slider3-pager span,#slider4-pager span{
 width:100px;
 height:15px;
 background:#fff;
 display:inline-block;
 border-radius:30em;
 opacity:0.6;
}
#slider3-pager .rslides_here a ,#slider4-pager .rslides_here a {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius:30em;
  opacity:1;
}
#slider3-pager a ,#slider4-pager a {
  padding: 0;
}
#slider3-pager li, #slider4-pager li{
 display:inline-block;
}
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.rslides li{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-info">
  <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
   <script>
         // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
         $(function () {
          // Slideshow 4
         $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
          auto: true,
          pager: true,
          nav: false,
          speed: 500,
          namespace: "callbacks",
          before: function () {
         $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
         },
         after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
          }
          });
          });
   </script>
  <div id="top" class="callbacks_container">
    <ol class="rslides" id="slider3">
     <li>
      <div class="banner-text">
       <h3>Strategic Benefits Design</h3>
       <h4>
                                                      We simplify HR so you can focus on your business!</h4>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="banner-text">
       <h3>Strategic Benefits Design</h3>
       <h4>We are committed to helping grow your business!</h4>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="banner-text">
       <h3>Strategic Benefits Design</h3>
       <h4>We give you exactly what you need!</h4>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try to reduce your code for better readability.

Comment: don't you mean javascript?

Comment: whatever the correct term is.  Do you know how to get the dots to go away?

Comment: It's hard to tell, based on the info you provided. I would check both JS and CSS. Did you try setting pager to false?
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true

Comment: The template you have has a slideshow.... Figure out how to removethe slideshow if you do not want it.

Comment: Please, please try reading the documentation for the plugin you're using before posting a question on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Your JavaScript is minified gobbledygook- without details on the library you're using (and non minified code) it would be very difficult to do. Best bet would be to read the documentation for the plugin you're using and if it's supported.

Comment: @Chris you can copy it over to JSFiddle and use their Tidy function, it does exactly what it says.

Comment: A question for http://diy.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You got the following code in your HTML file:

```
$("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true,
    nav: false,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function () {
```

Change `pager: true,` to `pager: false,` and see if it works. I don't know if it will for sure, but this would be the first thing I would try after seeing the [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) website.